# Yii2 querybuilder correct syntax for table names with raw sql

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Can anyone tell me what is it that I am doing wrong in this statement

```
$connection =   Yii::$app->db;
$result=$connection->createCommand("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 
                                   {{%promo_deliveries}}")->execute();
```

I am getting this error

> Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '`sms_promo_deliveries`' at line 1 The
>   SQL being executed was: `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE sms_promo_deliveries'
>
> in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\Nxb\sms_protected\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php:631
>
> Error Info: Array (
>       [0] => 42000
>       [1] => 1064
>       [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`sms_promo_deliveries`' at line 1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had nothing to do with the table naming convention when using query builder in fact it was a syntax error as specified, had to add quotes around the table name as i was using the `LIKE` keyword to match the table name.

```
$result=$connection->createCommand("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 
                                   '{{%promo_deliveries}}'")->execute();
```